# Can I maintain a (non-public) branch of a public github repo in a local TFS server?

Tags: git, github, tfs

I created a branch of a public github repo that I use locally to make changes I do not want to publish back to github. Now I'd like to make that branch available internally to other developers (and at the same time have it backed up properly rather than relying on my dev box's disk).

As we run a TFS server (which also has a git interface), I wonder if I can just maintain my private branch on our TFS server. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply can declare another Git repo, which would be associated to a different team (the "other developers") in a TFS second project.

Your current repo can then be pushed (with *all* its branches, including the private one)

```
cd /path/to/current/repo
git remote add private /tfs/url/of/second/repos
git push --mirror private
```

Your repo would then have two remote: the `origin` one (GitHub) and the `private` one TFS where you can push your private branch and collaborate with the other developers.

The OP adds in the comments:

> A more specific answer to my question - of putting a specific branch to a TFS server - I guess would be to use `git push --set-upstream private-repo private-branch`, which is what I'm doing now.

Comment: Can I then still contribute changes to the public branch back to github, without publishing the private one?

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky Sure: you can have multiple remote associated to your local repo. If you are on a public branch, it would be associated to origin (the GitHub repo). Only your private branch would be pushing to its upstream TFS private Git repo.

Comment: I tried `git remote add private https://my-repo.visualstudio.com/_git/my-project` on a freshly created (cloud-hosted, rather than on-premise as initially planned) repository followed by `git push --mirror`. Both commands completed without error, and the output of the push command suggests that my private branch as well as existing branches got pushed. But when doing a `git clone https://my-repo.visualstudio.com/_git/my-project`, the result is an empty directory. What's missing?

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky `git push --mirror` pushes by default to `origin`. Try `git push --mirror private`. I have edited the answer. Make sure you haven't pushed any private information to your public remote "origin" repo.

Comment: A more specific answer to my question - of putting a specific branch to a TFS server - I guess would be to use `git push --set-upstream private-repo private-branch`, which is what I'm doing now. I don't want to maintain master both at github and the private TFS server separately, as you'll then have to merge back and forth all the time.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky I agree, and have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.